# Mantine - Displaying a list of results until reaching parent height and then enable vertical overflow

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, css-grid, mantine

I am developing an web app that should fill `100vh` and `100vw` of the monitor.

The app itself should not scroll vertically or horizontally, but individual components/divs inside the app are allowed to scroll.

On the global css, I have the following defined

```css
body {
  background: none !important;
  margin: 0;
  user-select: none;
  height: 100vh !important;
  width: 100vw !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

I am using [Mantine](https://mantine.dev) as my components library in a React project.

The user is able to enter a search query, and it will return a list of search results.

I am using a [Stack](https://mantine.dev/core/stack/) to display the results.

If the list of search results is large enough to overflow the parent container's height, I want the Stack to be able to scroll vertically for the user to view the remaining search results.

```
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid p={8} gutter="lg">
        <Grid.Col span={4}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Search"
            label="Profile Search"
            icon={<IconSearch size={14} />}
            size="lg"
          />
          <Space h="lg" />

          <Stack sx={
            (theme) => (
              {
                overflowY: "auto",
              }
            )}>
            {/* repeated list of search results from query */}
            <SearchResult ... />
        </Stack>
      </Grid.Col>
    </Grid>
  )
```

I have attempted to wrap the Stack in a [ScrollArea](https://mantine.dev/core/scroll-area/), however this only works if I define the height to a fixed value.

```
<ScrollArea style={{ height: 500 }}>
  <Stack sx={ ... }>
    ...
  </Stack>
</ScrollArea>
```

This however does not give the behaviour I would like, as I want the results to be responsive and fill the height of the parent, and then overflow the remainder.

If, for example I set the height to 100%, the stack will overflow the parent, and the scroll never comes up.

```
<ScrollArea style={{ height: "100%" }}>
  <Stack sx={ ... }>
    ...
  </Stack>
</ScrollArea>
```

How do I use Mantine components to correctly display a list of search results until the max height of the parent, and then overflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for responsive height.

```
<ScrollArea.Autosize maxHeight={500}>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).